# Magento 2 How to Get selected data in innerlisting using ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

How to Get selected data in innerlisting using ui component?

[image]

Comment: are you opening a new grid once click on edit link from the main grid and you want to filter data as per edit it? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I have insertlisting in ui form when i edit form data i want to also edit grid selected data

Comment: inline editable ??

Comment: Nope please check inner listing in ui component in magento2